# Song from Naruto episode 12

Tags: naruto, music

Anyone knows the song played in episode 12 of Naruto (classic btw), when Kakashi is speaking with Inari? And it's not sadness and sorrow, neither grief and sorrow.

Comment: is there any reason to believe it's not Sadness and Sorrow? I found the section on Youtube you referenced, and it sounds like Sadness and Sorrow (or at least a very similar, possibly unreleased minor variation).

Comment: i'm saying it's not sadness and sorrow it's because doesn't sound like it, put both of them aside and they not sound alike, maybe can be another variation, but i didn't found it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the music from the scene where Kakashi is out with Inari out on the pier at night?

It sounds to me like a guitar-only version of Alone (OST 2 track 18). I don't think there's an official release of this variant, but there are imperfect [fan-spliced versions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RaZFe6ovNoU).